# Is this integral true? Or is it too much for Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

I was playing around with the wolfram calculator, just adding different things and mesmorising at what they equaled, then I randomly put in a bunch of trig functions, and well, this is what I got: 
$$
\int \cot(x)\cos(x)\sin(x)\tan(x)\sec(x)\csc(x)\,dx = x + C
$$

I don't know if this is a standard integral, but I'm pretty sure it's not, I tried googling it but all I found was a mix of random results, can someone please clear this up? I'm sure I can try to integrate this, but I don't want to get a heart-attack.

Comment: Note that $\cos$, $\sin$ and $\tan$ are the reciprocals of $\sec$, $\csc$ and $\cot$ respectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\int \cot x\cos x\sin x\tan x\sec x\csc xdx=\\
\int\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\cdot\frac{\cos x}{1}\cdot\frac{\sin x}{1}\cdot\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos x}\cdot\frac{1}{\sin x}dx=\int 1dx =x+C$$

Comment: amazing. I thought this would be the case, thank you for clearing things up!

Comment: @SamirChahine When dealing with trigonometric problems with unlike ratios, you should think about the relationship of other trigonometric ratios and try to write what you have in like terms as much as possible.

Comment: It's seriously amazing how something I thought to be an extremely painful equation to solve, easily turns out to be 1. Honestly, math is so cool

Comment: Indeed. Maths is very cool.

Answer (score 10):

**Hint**: Suppose I tell you that $\int f(x) dx = x + C$.  What can you then deduce about $f(x)$?

Comment: it has to equal 1, there for i'm guessing the identity $cos^2(x)+sin^2(x) = 1$ has a chance of being the simplified result if I wrote out all the functions in terms of $sin$ and $cos$?

Comment: @Samir: yes, it has to equal $1$.  This means that what you thought was a complicated integrand has to turn out to simply be the constant function $1$.  Once clued in to that it is easy to check....easier than you are making it out to be, in fact.  Just write out all the trig functions in terms of sine and cosine....

Answer (score 3):

Try simplifying the integrand by writing $\cot,\tan,\sec,\csc$ all in terms of $\sin,\cos$.

Comment: huh, didn't even think of that, thank you, will do.